# PL sql query to retrieve the value in below format

Tags: sql, plsql

Have to convert a amount field which will have values like -8825.23,0,85.36 into the format $0.00

Comment: The sample data contains multiple commas and multiple dots. So it doesn't represent a decimal number in any recognised notation. Please explain how you understand that data. For instance, presumably its datatype is a string not a numeric? Show that value as you want it to appear in the required format. Or perhaps that's just a typo? In which case please correct it. Either way, you need to clarify your question before you can get a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (Adjust code as required):

```
    declare
       v_amount number(38,2);
    begin

       select columnValue  into v_amount from myTable;
       
       dbms_output.put_line(to_char(v_amount,'L9G999G999G999D00'));

    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, try the TO_CHAR() function.

Comment: While technically correct this answer is not complete enough to be helpful to the Seeker.

Comment: Actually not sure this is even technically correct. On closer inspection the posted sample data is not a valid number, so it should already be a string. In which case suggesting TO_CHAR() is even less complete as an answer.